# Banner in Azure DevOps are not displayed

Tags: azure-devops

I want to display a message for all my Azure DevOps users. So, I use the `Azure DevOps CLI`. After the login

```
az login --organization xyz
```

I sent the command

```
az devops admin banner add 
    --org https://xyz.visualstudio.com
    --message "This is a warning" 
    --expiration 2022-07-21
    --type warning
```

and I received the confirmation. If I read the list of messages with

```
az devops admin banner list --org https://xyz.visualstudio.com
```

the banner and its details are there. The issue is that on the website there is no message or alert.

How can I display the message then?

Comment: Tested your code for my devops instance and it's working correctly. So that can't be the problem. Do you use a Azure Devops Cloud Instance or a devops server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Azure DevOps in the cloud